# mysql out_file default permission

Tags: mysql

When I use

```
SELECT "something" INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/somefile"
```

in MySQL, the created /tmp/somefile always seem to have the default permission of 0666.
Is there a way for me to specify in the query that I want it to be 0644 instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be modified dynamically, you need to set the [`UMASK` and/or `UMASK_DIR` environment variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html) accordingly and restart the server.

Comment: If I have set UMASK but the file permission remains 0666, is there a way to find out why?

Comment: What have you set UMASK to?

Comment: export UMASK=0644